Error Upgrade Ubuntu 22.04.04 - jammy security
Problem
hei guys i have error on upgrade . on update list source is normal and not error
i have try sudo apt update and sudo apt update --fix-mixing but the response is normal like
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                    
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:4 https://deb.termius.com squeeze InRelease                                                                                                                         
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:6 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:8 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                       
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 InRelease                                                    
Hit:10 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                         
Hit:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release                                     
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease                  
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
39 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


after i try to upgrade the ubuntu with sudo apt upgrade i get response error like this
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-6.5.0-18-generic linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-18 linux-image-6.5.0-18-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-18-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-18-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 vlc-data libvlccore9 vlc libavcodec-extra vlc-bin
  libpathplan4 vlc-l10n graphviz libavdevice58 libgvpr2 libgvc6 libpostproc55
  libcgraph6 vlc-plugin-samba libcdt5 libavcodec-extra58 vlc-plugin-notify
  libavutil56 libswscale5 vlc-plugin-access-extra libavutil-dev
  vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter liblab-gamut1 libswresample3
  vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev
  libvlc-bin libswresample-dev vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization
  libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bsdextrautils bsdutils code containerd.io curl docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin eject fdisk libblkid-dev libblkid1
  libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libfdisk1 libmount-dev libmount1 libsmartcols1 libuuid1 mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools mount rfkill termius-app util-linux uuid-dev uuid-runtime xserver-common xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-legacy xwayland
39 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
24 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 5,693 kB/399 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 mount amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 uuid-dev amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 uuid-runtime amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libblkid-dev amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libmount-dev amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 eject amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 bsdextrautils amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 libfdisk1 amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 fdisk amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 rfkill amd64 2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 xserver-common all 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
Err:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 xserver-xephyr amd64 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 xserver-xorg-legacy amd64 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 xserver-xorg-core amd64 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 xwayland amd64 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.12
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 xserver-common all 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/bsdutils_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/util-linux_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/mount_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libsmartcols1_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/uuid-dev_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libuuid1_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/uuid-runtime_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libblkid-dev_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libblkid1_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libmount-dev_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libmount1_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/eject_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/bsdextrautils_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/libfdisk1_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/fdisk_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/rfkill_2.37.2-4ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-common_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7%7e22.04.9_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xephyr_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7%7e22.04.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-legacy_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7%7e22.04.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-core_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7%7e22.04.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xwayland/xwayland_22.1.1-1ubuntu0.12_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


Ask
what the issue is from my ubuntu and i can fix by change anything ?
or
this is just issue from jammy-security source and i can't do anything ? just wait to be fixing this package from ubuntu company.

thank you very much for response guys. sorry for my bad english because this not my mother language.
i hope you all happy and health every time.

Please try sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* and sudo apt update to recreate the erased files and then again sudo apt upgrade or sudo apt full-upgrade

if do this is not make system issue right ? but i will try thank you.

Wiith sudo apt update the erased files will be recreated.  your apt is looking for outdated package versions. There are no longer available.

o right . thank you so much brother.

One correction to the command sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*. Since this is a directory you have to specify the recursive flag. The command sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* should become sudo rm -R /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
